# Crop an image in Android

Tags: android, image

How to crop a picture in Android?

When I open a picture with Google Photos, it doesn't show a crop option.
When I open with the in-built gallery app, it doesn't show the crop option.

But strangely, when I take a screenshot and click on the small thumbnail of the screenshot, it shows the option to crop the image. What could be the reason for this?

Any better or in-built way to crop an image?

Comment: Photos are usually JPEG/JPG files. The common format for screenshots is PNG. This may have an impact on the options shown.

Comment: For Google Photos, did you click the "Edit" button first? There should "Crop" option after that.

Comment: For in-built Gallery, that will depend on the device model since it's customizable by the manufacturer. The same for taking screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred app to edit photos is [Snapseed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed). It is simple but powerful and allows cropping and various other image manipulation techniques including adding text to a photo.

Another advantage is that it is from Google which means you can be sure that the app does not include malicious code. Of course an app from Google may collect privacy relevant data but I have not seen a deep integration of Google Cloud services or something like that.

Therefore you can simply open an photo from the gallery, crop it an directly export it as new image saved to your phone.

Comment: Thanks Snapseed seems cool. What are your favourite features? Also, I cropped an image but it didn't appear in my downloads folder. Do I have to manually export it or it saves it by default somewhere on the phone?

Comment: @Amitwadhwa The Tool "Text" is my favorite feature. Perfectly to create "digital post cards"  when you are on vacation and want to send something back home or if you want to create a digital greeting card based an own photo.

Answer (score 1):

> Any better or inbuilt way to crop an image?

The [Samsung Gallery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.gallery3d&hl=en&gl=US) app can crop an image. If you use a Samsung phone,  it'll likely has the Samsung Gallery app already installed.

Answer (score 1):

The [Screen Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pro.capture.screenshot&hl=en&gl=US) app can crop an image. It has a gratis version and many other useful features to edit images, e.g. add text, pixelate the image, and draw arrow/rect/circle.